# User log in php - mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, triggers

I have created a php page where I can create/edit/delete users. On top of that I wanted a log so I can see what has happened (users created/edited/deleted and by who - current logged in user - userid in session).

I have the first part running fine, I can create/edit/delete users and I can see everything in the log. My problem is that I can't see who has done the changes in the log. I made a workaround for the create/edit by inserting/updating the database with the current user, but it's not that easy with the delete.

I use triggers for the log table and it works fine, but I'm not really sure how I can make it save the current user in the database before deleting the selected user.

Currently I have three triggers, one with AFTER INSERT, one with AFTER UPDATE and one with AFTER DELETE.

Here is the code for when I insert a user in the database:
"members" is my table with all my users and "member_log" is my table with the log.

```
function insertUser($con) {
    $userid=$_SESSION['userid'];
    $str = "insert into members (username,password,fname,lname,email,memberrole_id,crud_user) values('".$_POST["username"]."',".
            "'".$_POST["password"]."',".
            "'".$_POST["fname"]."',".
            "'".$_POST["lname"]."',".
            "'".$_POST["email"]."',".
            "'".$_POST["userrole"]."',".
            "'".$userid."')";
    $con->query($str);
}
```

The important part is the "crud_user" and its value. I get the same data in the Log table and it shows perfectly (might not be the best way to archive this, but it works - you're welcome to suggest a better way to do it as well).

Here is the delete function with the code I tried earlier:

```
function deleteUser($con) {
    //$userid=$_SESSION['userid'];
    //$deleteduserid = $_GET["id"];
    /*$userid=$_SESSION['userid'];
    $str1 = "update member_log set crud_user='".$userid."' where id=".$_GET["id"];
    $con->query($str1);*/
    $str2 = "delete from members where id=" . $_GET["id"];
    $con->query($str2);
}
```

If I use the first part of it I get two rows in my Log instead of just the one (one for updating and one for deleting, I would like to just have the deleted one with the Current User).

So what I really want is to be able to see which user has deleted the selected user. At the moment I just get the user shown who has created/updated the user the last time, because I have no code to change that user in the delete function/trigger.

I tried the above to fix it and I also looked into "BEFORE DELETE" triggers, but I'm not really sure how to get my Current User in there.

If I have explained it in a bad way, just tell me and I'll try to explain it a little bit better.

Thank you

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) alert

Comment: I might add that it's not for a public website, just an exercise.
(there's no security/validating stuff either)

Comment: So, just to make things clear, you want to log which user deletes a user from the table? You could update the log with the current user (via php) after you have deleted the user in the table.

Comment: Ah right.
Moved this code 
"$str1 = "update member_log set crud_user='".$userid."' where action='delete' and id=".$_GET["id"];
 $con->query($str1);"
under the delete and added the "action='delete'" and I got it to work. I suppose not the best way, but it works now.
Thanks for getting my focus back on that part!